# Why are my variables not updating on screen?

Tags: python, pygame

```
# DONT CHANGE THIS
import pygame, os
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 450, 250
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))   
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Spar")

# VARIABLES
HEALTH_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
WINNER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
WINCOUNT_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
SPACE = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "space.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 5, HEIGHT)
FPS = 60
VEL = 3.5
SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT, = 25, 20
BULLETS_VEL = 10
MAX_BULLETS = 1
YELLOW_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
RED_HIT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', "spaceship_yellow.png"))    
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SHIP_HEIGHT, SHIP_WIDTH)), 90)
RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', "spaceship_red.png"))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)), 270)

# PLACE ANYTHING ON THE WINDOW HERE
# +y = down from top left 
# +x = right from top left
def draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_health, yellow_health, red_win_count, yellow_win_count):
  WIN.blit(SPACE, (0, 0))
  pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
  red_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(red_health), 1, WHITE)
  yellow_health_text = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(yellow_health), 1, WHITE)
  WIN.blit(red_health_text, (WIDTH - red_health_text.get_width() - 10, 10))
  WIN.blit(yellow_health_text, (10, 10))
  yellow_win_text = WINCOUNT_FONT.render('Wins: ' + str(yellow_win_count), 1, WHITE)
  red_win_text = WINCOUNT_FONT.render('Wins: ' + str(red_win_count), 1, WHITE)
  WIN.blit(red_win_text, (WIDTH - red_health_text.get_width() - 70, 10))
  pygame.display.update() 
  WIN.blit(yellow_win_text, (70, 10))
  pygame.display.update() 

  WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
  WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y))
  for bullet in red_bullets:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)
  for bullet in yellow_bullets:
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, bullet)

  
  pygame.display.update() 

# MOVEMENT
def yellow_movement(keys_pressed, yellow):
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VEL > 0:  #left
      yellow.x -= VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + VEL + yellow.width < BORDER.x:  #right
      yellow.x += VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - VEL > 0:  #up
      yellow.y -= VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + VEL + yellow.height < HEIGHT:  #dowm
      yellow.y += VEL

def red_movement(keys_pressed, red):
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x - VEL > BORDER.x + BORDER.width:  #left
      red.x -= VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x + VEL + red.width < WIDTH:  #right
      red.x += VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and red.y - VEL > 0:  #up
      red.y -= VEL
  if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]  and red.y + VEL + red.height < HEIGHT:  #dowm
      red.y += VEL

def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
  for bullet in yellow_bullets:
    bullet.x += BULLETS_VEL
    if red.colliderect(bullet):
      pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(RED_HIT))
      yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)
    elif bullet.x > WIDTH:
      yellow_bullets.remove(bullet)
      
  for bullet in red_bullets:
    bullet.x -= BULLETS_VEL
    if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
      pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(YELLOW_HIT))
      red_bullets.remove(bullet)
    elif bullet.x < 0:
      red_bullets.remove(bullet)
    
def draw_winner(text):
  draw_text = WINNER_FONT.render(text, 1, WHITE)
  WIN.blit(draw_text, (WIDTH//2 - draw_text.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - draw_text.get_height()/2))
  pygame.display.update()
  pygame.time.delay(1000)
  
  
    
# MAIN LOOP 
def main():
  red = pygame.Rect(350, 150,SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)
  yellow = pygame.Rect(50, 150, SHIP_WIDTH, SHIP_HEIGHT)

  red_bullets = []
  yellow_bullets = []

  red_health = 1
  yellow_health = 1
  red_win_count = 0
  yellow_win_count = 0
  
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()
  run = True
  while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False 
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and len(yellow_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
          bullet = pygame.Rect(yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2 - 1, 15, 4)
          yellow_bullets.append(bullet)

        if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL and len(red_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:
          bullet = pygame.Rect(red.x, red.y + red.height//2 - 1, 15, 4)
          red_bullets.append(bullet)
      if event.type == RED_HIT:
        red_health -= 1
      if event.type == YELLOW_HIT:
        yellow_health -= 1
    winner_text = ""
    if red_health <= 0:
      yellow_win_count += 1
      pygame.display.update()
      winner_text = "Yellow is cooler" 
    if yellow_health <= 0:
      winner_text = "Red is cooler"
      red_win_count += 1
      pygame.display.update()
    if winner_text != "":
      draw_winner(winner_text)
      main()
      
        


    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    yellow_movement(keys_pressed, yellow)
    red_movement(keys_pressed, red)

    handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red)
    
    draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets, red_health, yellow_health, red_win_count, yellow_win_count)
  pygame.quit()

# this is to make sure its opening the right thing blah blaho
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm trying to display a win count through a variable but the variable isn't updating on the screen, why?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) | [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't see where you're drawing the win count on the screen.  Did I miss it?

Comment: WIN.blit(yellow_win_text, (70, 10))

Comment: You are calling `main` recursively to start the next game.  That's a horrible practice.  Use a loop instead.  The net result is that you are resetting all of your win counts every time you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the Github version of this game and determined that what you are wanting to do is add an enhancement that shows wins on the screen.  The issue at the moment is that once a spaceship wins and the program again starts "main()", the win variables get reset to "0" before the screen is redisplayed.

```
red_health = 1
yellow_health = 1
red_win_count = 0
yellow_win_count = 0
```

As a quick tweak, instead of constantly restarting the game by calling "main" at the end of the "while" block, I revised the last "if" block to just do the resetting of the player health and then continue on with the while loop function.

```
if winner_text != "":
  draw_winner(winner_text)
  red_health = 4
  yellow_health = 4
  continue
  #main()
```

That then allowed for viewing the win count on the screen.

[image: Demo Screen]

You might want to check to see if any other variables need to be reset, but you can give that a try.